# Wordpress Page Builder Doesn't Save or Close

Tags: wordpress

color-picker.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

```
at a.(/anonymous function).(anonymous function).close  
(http://www.callpointtechsolutions.com/wp-admin/js/color-picker.min.js? 
ver=4.9.8:1:3088)  
at a.(/anonymous function).(anonymous function).close  
(http://www.callpointtechsolutions.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11:1032)  

at a.(/anonymous function).(anonymous function).d [as close]  
(http://www.callpointtechsolutions.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:3856)

at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)  
at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)  
at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)  
at a.fn.init.a.fn.(/anonymous function) [as wpColorPicker]  
(http://www.callpointtechsolutions.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11:1857)  
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (frontend_pagebuilder.bundle.js?ver=4.5.1:1539)  
at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)  
at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```